# Fails to build app using firebase_auth: ^0.20.0+1

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm facing problem when i try to build my app when using firebase auth:

```
import 'package:firbasetest/user.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
class authmethods{
  final FirebaseAuth auth =FirebaseAuth.instance;
  UserAuth userfromfirebase(User userz)
  {
    return userz!=null? UserAuth(userz.uid) :null;
  }
  Future signinWithEmailandPassword(String email, String passowrd) async
  {
    try{
      UserCredential result = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: passowrd);
      User firebaseUser=result.user;
      return userfromfirebase(firebaseUser);
    }
    catch(e){print(e);}
  }

  Future signupwithemailandpassword(String email,String password) async
  {
    try{
      UserCredential result = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      User firebaseUser=result.user;
      return userfromfirebase(firebaseUser);
    }
    catch(e){print(e);}
  }

  Future signout() async
  {
    try{
      return await auth.signOut();
    }
    catch(e){print(e);}
  }
}
```

---

### dependencies :
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
firebase_core: ^0.7.0
firebase_auth: ^0.20.0+1

Error output :

> /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.20.0+1/lib/firebase_auth.dart:9:8:
> Error: Error when reading
> '/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_platform_interface-3.0.1/lib/firebase_core_platform_interface.dart':
> The system cannot find the path specified.
>
> import
> 'package:firebase_core_platform_interface/firebase_core_platform_interface.dart';
> ^ /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.20.0+1/lib/firebase_auth.dart:52:1:
> Error: Error when reading
> '/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_platform_interface-3.0.1/lib/firebase_core_platform_interface.dart':
> The system cannot find the path specified.
>
> export
> 'package:firebase_core_platform_interface/firebase_core_platform_interface.dart'
> ^
> /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.7.0/lib/firebase_core.dart:7:8:
> Error: Error when reading
> '/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_platform_interface-3.0.1/lib/firebase_core_platform_interface.dart':
> The system cannot find the path specified.
>
> import
> 'package:firebase_core_platform_interface/firebase_core_platform_interface.dart'
> ^ /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.7.0/lib/firebase_core.dart:12:1:
> Error: Error when reading
> '/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_platform_interface-3.0.1/lib/firebase_core_platform_interface.dart':
> The system cannot find the path specified.
>
> export
> 'package:firebase_core_platform_interface/firebase_core_platform_interface.dart'
> ^
> /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.20.0+1/lib/src/firebase_auth.dart:8:28:
> Error: Type 'FirebasePluginPlatform' not found. class FirebaseAuth
> extends FirebasePluginPlatform {
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.7.0/lib/src/firebase_app.dart:11:3:
> Error: Type 'FirebaseAppPlatform' not found.   FirebaseAppPlatform
> _delegate;   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.7.0/lib/src/firebase_app.dart:34:3:
> Error: Type 'FirebaseOptions' not found.   FirebaseOptions get options
> => _delegate.options;   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.7.0/lib/src/firebase.dart:16:10:
> Error: Type 'FirebasePlatform' not found.   static FirebasePlatform
> delegatePackingProperty;
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.7.0/lib/src/firebase.dart:18:10:
> Error: Type 'FirebasePlatform' not found.   static FirebasePlatform
> /*!*/ get _delegate {
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.7.0/lib/src/firebase.dart:41:27:
> Error: Type 'FirebaseOptions' not found.
> {String /*?*/ name, FirebaseOptions /*?*/ options}) async {
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-3.0.1/lib/src/firebase_auth_exception.dart:11:37:
> Error: Type 'FirebaseException' not found. class FirebaseAuthException
> extends FirebaseException implements Exception {
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-3.0.1/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:27:1:
> Error: Type 'FirebaseException' not found. FirebaseException
> platformExceptionToFirebaseAuthException( ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.20.0+1/lib/src/firebase_auth.dart:24:38:
> Error: The getter 'pluginConstants' isn't defined for the class
> 'FirebaseAuth'.
>
> - 'FirebaseAuth' is from 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.20.0+1/lib/firebase_auth.dart').
>   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining
>   a getter or field named 'pluginConstants'.
>   app: app, pluginConstants: pluginConstants);
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.20.0+1/lib/src/firebase_auth.dart:33:14:
>   Error: Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 2 found. Try
>   removing the extra positional arguments.
>   : super(app.name, 'plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth');
>   ^ /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.7.0/lib/src/firebase_app.dart:11:3:
>   Error: 'FirebaseAppPlatform' isn't a type.   FirebaseAppPlatform
>   _delegate;   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.7.0/lib/src/firebase_app.dart:19:5:
>   Error: The getter 'FirebaseAppPlatform' isn't defined for the class
>   'FirebaseApp'.
> - 'FirebaseApp' is from 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.7.0/lib/firebase_core.dart').
>   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining
>   a getter or field named 'FirebaseAppPlatform'.
>   FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends(_delegate);
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.7.0/lib/src/firebase.dart:16:10:
>   Error: 'FirebasePlatform' isn't a type.   static FirebasePlatform
>   delegatePackingProperty;
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.7.0/lib/src/firebase.dart:20:33:
>   Error: Getter not found: 'FirebasePlatform'.
>   delegatePackingProperty = FirebasePlatform.instance;
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.7.0/lib/src/firebase.dart:41:27:
>   Error: 'FirebaseOptions' isn't a type.
>   {String /*?*/ name, FirebaseOptions /*?*/ options}) async {
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.7.0/lib/src/firebase.dart:43:5:
>   Error: 'FirebaseAppPlatform' isn't a type.
>   FirebaseAppPlatform app =
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.7.0/lib/src/firebase.dart:52:41:
>   Error: Getter not found: 'defaultFirebaseAppName'.   static
>   FirebaseApp app([String name = defaultFirebaseAppName]) {
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.7.0/lib/src/firebase.dart:53:5:
>   Error: 'FirebaseAppPlatform' isn't a type.
>   FirebaseAppPlatform app = _delegate.app(name);
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-3.0.1/lib/src/firebase_auth_exception.dart:21:15:
>   Error: No named parameter with the name 'plugin'.
>   : super(plugin: 'firebase_auth', message: message, code: code);
>   ^^^^^^
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 904
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
>
> > Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 2m 47s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed
> with exit code 1

Comment: Check this link to an answer to the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/74367061/8720836

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a few things. Run

```
flutter clean
```

to clean your build. Then please check, whether the path to firebase actually exists, if you have a directory named "flutter" directly after C:\

Please provide more information about your firebase environment. Have you added the app to firebase already and added the package name, sha1... and so on?

Comment: Yes the path does exist and i have added the package name to my firebase project and downloaded the json file and imported it to the app ... also i have initialized firebase in the main class but the error still showing up