# FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends error while running flutter test

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter-test, flutter-objectbox

When I run my bitbucket pipeline for my project im getting an error during flutter test:

```
/root/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/firebase_app.dart:18:25: Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'.
    FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends(_delegate);
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

When I run flutter test in my terminal I don't have these issues.

My pipeline script is:

- Build Setup
- flutter clean
- flutter pub get
- flutter pub run build_runner build
- bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/main/install.sh)
- flutter test

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74226250/error-member-not-found-firebaseappplatform-verifyextends)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Because there are some breaking change of `firebase_core_platform_interface` that do not comply with semantic versioning:
https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9806

You need to overwrite this library:

[image]

Answer (score 21):

***Root cause***

You are update or installing only a subset of the Firebase plugins (firebase_core, firebase_analytics,...)

***Solution***

- **Solution 1**: (preferred) Updating to the latest version with **flutterfire update** check the docs [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli/). But it is not easily because your project will have a lot of packages dependencies to each other like **flutter version 2 or 3**, so on. Anyway, it is long term solution.
- **Solution 2**: (Fix to run)
  You can add to your pubspec.yaml

  ```
   dependency_overrides:
      firebase_core_platform_interface: 4.5.1
  ```
- **Solution 3**: (Fix to run)
  Update dependencies with this below **command line**:

  ```
   flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
  ```

**Finally**, Run the project again by following stuffs:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
cd ios && rm -f Podfile.lock
cd ios && pod install --repo-update
flutter run
```

That's it!

Answer (score 5):

Run "flutter pub upgrade --major-versions"

Answer (score 1):

run this
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
than run this
flutter upgrade

Answer (score 0):

I changed my flutter version via `flutter channel master`. This changed automatically my `pubspec.lock`.
In my case, restoring previous version of `pubspec.lock` solved the problem (`pug get` needed).