# Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'. FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends(_delegate); Flutter error

Tags: flutter, firebase

I was making my flutter firebase project when I ran into this error. how to resolve this?

my `pubspec.yaml` file is

```
 name: multi_store_app
description: By RRB Productions

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.19.0-201.0.dev <3.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  animated_text_kit: ^4.2.2
  image_picker: ^0.8.6
  firebase_auth: ^3.11.2
  cloud_firestore: ^3.5.1
  firebase_storage: ^10.3.11
  firebase_core: ^1.24.0
  firebase_app_check: ^0.0.9+1
  uuid: ^3.0.6
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.6.2
  staggered_grid_view_flutter: ^0.0.4
  

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - images/accessories/
    - images/bags/
    - images/try/ 
    - images/beauty/
    - images/electronics/
    - images/homegarden/
    - images/inapp/
    - images/kids/
    - images/men/
    - images/shoes/
    - images/women/

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
  fonts:
    - family: Acme
      fonts: 
        - asset: fonts/Acme-Regular.ttf



[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: same with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74228526/firebaseappplatform-verifyextends-error-while-running-flutter-test/74230249#74230249

Answer (score 7):

After a research I found the answer,

It was a bug in the firebase packages.
I added the exact version of  `firebase_core_platform_interface`

```
firebase_core_platform_interface: 4.5.1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either add below code in `pubspec.yaml`

```
firebase_core_platform_interface: 4.5.1
```

OR

Run `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`

For more details refer : [Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74226250/error-member-not-found-firebaseappplatform-verifyextends)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade `firebase_core`, `firebase_storage`, `firebase_auth`and `cloud_firestore` manually one by one by using `flutter pub upgrade [package_name]` command. Hopefully this solves your issue