# Flutter build - getting error - DataSnapshotPlatform.verifyExtends, OnDisconnectPlatform.verifyExtends

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-build

Started getting below errors for iOS build today.

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/zm/0n9b6r1d0pv73j14vwr1w5s80000gn/T/flutter_tools.EuJlha/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirqOJbPP/temporary_xcresult_bundle
: Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verify'.
../…/src/firebase_app.dart:18
        FirebaseAppPlatform.verify(_delegate);
                            ^^^^^^
: Error: Member not found: 'DataSnapshotPlatform.verifyExtends'.
../…/src/data_snapshot.dart:9
        DataSnapshotPlatform.verifyExtends(_delegate);
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Error: Member not found: 'DatabaseEventPlatform.verifyExtends'.
../…/src/database_event.dart:13
        DatabaseEventPlatform.verifyExtends(_delegate);
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Error: Member not found: 'OnDisconnectPlatform.verifyExtends'.
../…/src/on_disconnect.dart:27
        OnDisconnectPlatform.verifyExtends(_delegate);
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Error: Member not found: 'TransactionResultPlatform.verifyExtends'.
../…/src/transaction_result.dart:12
        TransactionResultPlatform.verifyExtends(_delegate);
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I tried steps from other similar question on SO - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74580648/13766036

Still build issue is there.

```
dependency_overrides:
  firebase_database: 10.0.1
  firebase_auth: 4.1.3
  firebase_core: 2.3.0
  firebase_storage: 11.0.6
  firebase_core_platform_interface: 4.5.1
```

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
cd ios && rm -f Podfile.lock
cd ..
cd ios && pod install --repo-update
cd ..
flutter run
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated my **pubspec.yaml** to use **latest firebase** packages available

```
  firebase_auth: 4.2.0
  firebase_core: 2.4.0
  firebase_database: 10.0.7
  firebase_storage: 11.0.7
```

Removed any *dependency_overrides* of firebase packages from pubspec.yaml

finally did below steps

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
cd ios 
rm -f Podfile.lock
pod install --repo-update
cd ..
flutter run
```

Above worked for me, and issue is resolved.